# FL Studio: Deciding the synthesizer for a notebased on its MIDI channel

Tags: midi, synthesizer, daw, fl-studio, audio-editing

**Is it possible to, using a patcher channel, play notes of one midi channel through one synthesizer, and play notes of another midi channel through another synthesizer?**

**Example:** I have a basic melody, and I want one note to be played through a different synthesizer without having to use a separate channel, or an automation clip to auto-enable the synthesizer just for that note. Let's say that every note in this melody is green *(midi channel 1)* except for the one note I want to change. That one will be orange *(midi channel 13)* and it should be played through a separate synthesizer.

**Is this feasible and if so, how?**

Comment: I’m a bit confused. In one sentence you ask about using separate channels and in another sentence you say you don’t want to use a separate channel. Can you clarify whether you are trying to change synthesizers without changing channels or whether it’s ok to have different notes on different channels?

Comment: im wondering if one FL track (like a patcher) can have 2 seperate synthesizers on it, each accepting notes from individual midi channels.

Comment: I'm pretty sure Kontakt allows input from multiple midi channels where you can specify it per instrument, but I'm not sure if it would work in Patcher

Comment: It isn't that much harder/resource using to simply use two different instances and use them in the same pattern, as the piano roll allows you to have more than one instrument playing in a pattern, and it's pretty easy to switch between what instrument is viewed

Comment: MIDI channels are originally meant for the purpose you are describing. Receiving devices/plugins should be able to respond to a single incoming channel. Whether you can set channels per note in a sequence depends on the piano roll editing features, but most piano rolls allow this. Sometimes, the "Event" view mode is better suited for what you want. There should be an "event list" mode that treats the sequence as a top-down list of events.